# Select a child of a child

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why can't I select a child of a child in jQuery? I want to add a class to a child of a child using `.children()` method and the `>` selector. See code below:

```
$(function(){
        // main expansion element
        $(".expander").click(function() {
            var subShown = $(this).children("ul > li").hasClass("show");
            if (!subShown) {
                $(this).children(".indented").slideDown('100').addClass("show");
                $(this).children(".caret").addClass("reversedCaret");
            } else {
                $(this).children(".indented").slideUp('100').removeClass("show");
                $(this).children(".caret").removeClass("reversedCaret");
            }
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="expander">
                  <span class="caret downCaret right visibleCaret">+</span>
                  <ul>
                  <li class="category">Item 1<a href="http://www.google.com"></a></li>
                  <li class="indented"><a href="http://www.google.com">Item 2</a></li>
                  <li class="indented"><a href="http://www.google.com">Item 3</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
```

When I click on `expander` it will not add the class to my `li` elements. Why?

Comment: The `li` are not direct children of the expander, which is what `children()` returns.  You will need to use `find()` instead of `children()`.  `children()` is essentially the same as `find('> *')`

Comment: I tried `.find()` but I couldn't get it working properly. would it go before or after `.children()`?

Comment: Look at Scott's solution.  You don't -have- to use children() at all.

Comment: Your jQuery code is very fragile.  I recommend reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

Comment: @Taplar But I'm not understanding why `.children()` didn't work...so the `li` I want is two levels down from expander div, right? So `.children()` would have given me the `ul` element, and then from there if I used `>` to target the li to check for the class? What is the piece I am/was missing here?

Comment: The selector in the `children()` is only applied against those elements, and since the li's are not direct children, the filter in children wouldn't match them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the **[JQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/children/)** on `.children()`:

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well.

You really don't even need to be using `.children()` for this at all. The much simpler solution is to just **[provide context for your queries](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1)** by passing a second argument to JQuery after the selector.

```js
$(function(){
        // main expansion element
        $(".expander").click(function() {
        
           // Just for demonstration: *************************************************
           
            // 2 because of <span> and <ul>
           console.log($(this).children().length);          
           
           // 0 because anything beyond children isn't returned in the first place
           console.log($(this).children("ul > li").length); 
           // *************************************************************************
        
            //  By passing "this" as the second argument to JQuery, after the selector,
            //  it sets the context for the search to only "this", so the entire DOM
            //  is not searched, just the object that "this" is bound to.
            var subShown = $("ul > li", this).hasClass("show");
            if (!subShown) {
                $(".indented", this).slideDown('100').addClass("show");
                $(".caret", this).addClass("reversedCaret");
            } else {
                $(".indented", this).slideUp('100').removeClass("show");
                $(".caret", this).removeClass("reversedCaret");
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expander">
  <span class="caret downCaret right visibleCaret">+</span>
  <ul>
    <li class="category">Item 1<a href="http://www.google.com"></a></li>
    <li class="indented"><a href="http://www.google.com">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="indented"><a href="http://www.google.com">Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this - but I'm still having a hard time understanding why my version didn't work? So if `.children()` goes down one level in dom tree, and my li is two levels down from the div. So with that in mind, shouldn't have using `.children()` and the `>` selector given me what I wanted?

Comment: @kawnah The `.children()` method returns a wrapped set of **only** the child elements. So, even though your selector says to search deeper from there, the set of elements that the search will take place on just doesn't have any elements at a lower depth.

Comment: @kawnah I have updated the answer to include some demonstrations that show that calling `.children()` will only return the immediate child nodes and nothing else beyond that. So trying to search deeper returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.find('>ul>li')`, example:

```
var expander = $(".expander")

expander.on('click', function(){
  var li = expender.find('>ul>li')
  li.hasClass("show")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to approach it as you are (and not as the given answer does, which is better by the way), then change this

```
$(this).children("ul > li")
```

to this:

```
$(this).children('ul').children()
```

Selecting children of `ul` that is.

Comment: ok.. I'm moving forward with Scott Marcus's answer but thank you

Answer (score 0):

`.querySelector`

```js
document.querySelector("section > div").classList.add("my-gray");
```

```css
.my-gray{
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<section>
Foo
<div>
Bar
</div>
</section>
```